# How to get the id of a tag and apply to manipulate the contents of ul

Tags: jquery

I am trying to retrieve the string contained in multiple unordered lists. The script below gets the ul id ( alert(`sentenceId`)), but in the next line when I try to use `sentenceId` as identifier to retrieve the string, I get nothing.

```js
$('#quiz').find('ul').each(function() {
  let sentenceId = $(this).attr('id');
  alert(sentenceId)
  sentence = $.map($('#sentenceId li'), function(element) {
    return $(element).text()
  }).join(' ');
  alert(sentence)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='quiz'>
  <ul class="scramble" id="Q1">
    <li>I</li>
    <li>piano</li>
    <li>can't</li>
    <li>play</li>
    <li>the</li>
    <button onclick="checkOrd(id);">Check</button>
  </ul>

  <ul class="scramble" id="Q2">
    <li>moon</li>
    <li>green</li>
    <li>is</li>
    <li>disc</li>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>the</li>
    <button onclick="getOrd(id);">Check</button>
  </ul>
</div>
```

How do I use my sentenceId as the id for each unique list? If I replace #sentenceId with #Q1 or #Q2, I get the string returned.

Comment: Even before you changed your question content, I have answered and solved it. Check out my answer.

Comment: Looks like this question is a typo and should be deleted. Ahh! `:(` Feel free to delete the question as it is solved.

Comment: You have deleted the answer as well. Don't know how duplication occurred.

Comment: Yeah, kinda... Do you want me to restore that answer so you can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `sentenceId` is a variable and you should use this way:

```
$('#' + sentenceId + ' li')
```

```js
$('#quiz').find('ul').each(function() {
  let sentenceId = $(this).attr('id');
  alert(sentenceId);
  sentence = $.map($('#' + sentenceId + ' li'), function(element) {
    return $(element).text();
  }).join(' ');
  alert(sentence)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='quiz'>
  <ul class="scramble" id="Q1">
    <li>I</li>
    <li>piano</li>
    <li>can't</li>
    <li>play</li>
    <li>the</li>
    <button onclick="checkOrd(id);">Check</button>
  </ul>

  <ul class="scramble" id="Q2">
    <li>moon</li>
    <li>green</li>
    <li>is</li>
    <li>disc</li>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>the</li>
    <button onclick="getOrd(id);">Check</button>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Have accepted. Tried to upvote , but it tells me I have already voted. I did , but I upvoted!! Its an excellent and very helpful answer and has solved my query. Don't know whats going on with voting today. My fingers!

Comment: @user1478335 All fine... Don't worry... `:D`

Answer (score -2):

You do not have to find the `id` in order to search deeper. Since you have a reference to the `ul` you can search deeper from there

```js
$('#quiz').find('ul').each(function() {
  /*
  // not required
  const sentenceId = this.id; 
  alert(sentenceId)
  */
  const ul = $(this);
  const sentence = $.map(ul.find('li'), function(element) {
    return $(element).text()
  }).join(' ');
  alert(sentence)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='quiz'>
  <ul class="scramble" id="Q1">
    <li>I</li>
    <li>piano</li>
    <li>can't</li>
    <li>play</li>
    <li>the</li>
    <button onclick="checkOrd(id);">Check</button>
  </ul>

  <ul class="scramble" id="Q2">
    <li>moon</li>
    <li>green</li>
    <li>is</li>
    <li>disc</li>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>the</li>
    <button onclick="getOrd(id);">Check</button>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't even run.